# XSL change value within current node

Tags: xml, xslt

if i have an xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <Name>Derek</Name>
            <City>Seattle</City>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Name>Bob</Name>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

and xsl as :

```
<xsl:param name="Criteria1" />
<xsl:param name="Cirteria1AddBeforeText" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Rowsets>
        <xsl:if test="count(/Rowsets/FatalError) = '0'">
            <xsl:for-each select="/Rowsets/Rowset">
                <Rowset>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Rowset>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </Rowsets>
</xsl:template>
```

how can change the xsl so that the :

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

part of the xsl is replaced with code that checks to see if the node name is the same as the paramater F1 so that i can output say for Criteria1= City, Cirteria1AddBeforeText= "City : "

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <Name>Derek</Name>
            <City>City : Seattle</City>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Name>Bob</Name>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

What i am looking for really is to understand how the current node-set of a for-each statement can be modified so that specific elements are altered based on input parameters keeping all other rows if the criteria is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't change the input nodes as such, what you need to do is to use templates instead of the `copy-of` to create modified nodes as appropriate.  I'd approach this problem by starting with an "identity transformation" and then adding a special case for child elements of `Row`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="Criteria1" />
  <xsl:param name="Cirteria1AddBeforeText" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="name() = $Criteria1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Cirteria1AddBeforeText" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the "fatal error" logic you could add an additional template

```
<xsl:template match="Rowsets[FatalError]">
  <Rowsets>There was a fatal error</Rowsets>
</xsl:template>
```

(or whatever logic you want for the fatal error case) and this would take precedence over the identity template if there are any `FatalError` elements under the input `Rowsets`.

Answer (score 0):

Ian Roberts already gave you the answer. I just wanted to point out that in your current stylesheet:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
```

is the same thing as:

```
                <xsl:copy-of select="Row" />
```

and similarly:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="/Rowsets/Rowset">
            <Rowset>
                <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Rowset>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

could be expressed simply as:

```
        <xsl:copy-of select="Rowsets/Rowset" />
```